# Bashscript as Systemd Service: If statement returns always false

Tags: shell, scripting, raspbian, systemd

I have a small script which I turned into a systemd Service. 
If I run the script as a service an easy if statement returns alwayws false , if I call the script manual as a user or superuse the statement is true:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "test" == "test"]
then
echo "if ist true" | logger 2>&1
else
echo "if ist false" | logger 2>&1
fi
```

actually I tried to find as substring, but to make it simple I have this statement now running, with the same problem...

Comment: Try `[ "test" == "test" ]` (note the space before the `]`). Without the space, `[` complains of a syntax error and returns false, as it should.

Comment: ok the original has the space... but the problem still persists ..

Answer (score 0):

ok , I cleard the problem using grep. Its strange , but all syntax I tried with if did not work at all , if I started the script as a service ... but anyway.. with grep everything was easy:

```
file=myentirestring

if echo "$file" | grep -q "entire"; then
    echo "true" 
else
    echo "false"
fi
```